# SharePoint (2016) list - add field that doesn't ask for input

Tags: sharepoint

Need a field in my list that does not show up/prompts for input on the New Item list. The values in that field will be populated by another user days later when they are known. Automation that connects with the list would run additional procedures if the value is present.

Tried hiding the column, but it still shows up in the New Item list.

As a workaround, I could add a field with a comment "leave blank" but thought there is a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that you've tried to hide the field by content type, right?
If not, this is the best solution.

Another approach is to hide the field using javascript.
From SPD, you can edit the New and Edit Forms.

It's not a bealty solution, but would work.

Comment: "hide the field by content type" - that did it, thank you!